# Is position 'initial' cross-browser - css

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, css-position

I have a css conflict, so I have to go against an absolute positioning property that deals with some class `.myclass`. But in one case, I want a div with `.myclass` class to have a no absolute positioning. So I put `position: initial`, which works in Chrome, but is it cross-browser? I googled it and found nothing really precise.

Comment: Use inherit. Initial have been used since 2011. IE doesn't support initial.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The default for position is `position: static;`

Comment: Just tested replacing the "position: initial;" for "position: static;" and it worked.

Answer (score 24):

The [`initial`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#initial) keyword was introduced in 2011 in the [Cascading and Inheritance Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/) -- it's supported in FF 19<sup>+</sup>, Chrome, Safari, Opera 15<sup>+</sup> but is currently [not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508(v=vs.85).aspx#keywords) in any version of IE.

Comment: Ah, it is [a new generic keyword](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#initial), that explains why it wasn't listed in the [css positioning spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#position-property) (that spec, I assume, hasn't been updated since it was added)

Comment: @Quentin: It says "Initial: static" in its propdef. The term "initial value" has been in use since CSS1 to mean something like "the spec default value for this property if unspecified."

Comment: @BoltClock — This answer, while describing the right thing, linked to the wrong thing. I followed links to find it, but it is talking about the *`initial` keyword* not the *initial value*. I've edited the answer to point to the correct place.

Comment: @Quentin: I know - I'm simply stating that the keyword was introduced to allow access to the long-existent concept of an initial value.

Answer (score 8):

Even IE 11 gives me the 'squiggles' for this one. Changing to `static` gave me the desired behavior.

[image]

Chrome actually suggests it as an acceptable property in its dropdown

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as `position: unset;` wasn't working for me in IE. I changed `position: static;` and it worked as expected as IE doesn't have unset behavior.