# Foundation sticky only on mobile

Tags: sticky, zurb-foundation-6

How can I have a sticky element with Foundation that sticks only on small breakpoints?  `data-sticky-on="small"` works for small and up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those interested. I have found this solution when using sass.

```
//Desktop settings
@include breakpoint(medium) {
    //Disable fixed top bar on mobile
    .sticky {
        position: initial !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could replace `position: initial` with `static`, since `position: initial` isn't supported by certain versions of IE (source: [Position initial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15343567/2228912)).

Comment: I would add `margin-top: 0 !important` as a top-margin was affected to the `sticky` when you scroll.